# Name change from AA BB, FNU in US Visa to BB,AA

Tags: visas, usa, passports, indian-citizens, applications

Due to a mistake I did while applying for passport[INDIA], the surname section in my passport is empty and given name section has "AA BB". My name in university application and in other places like GRE/TOEFL is in the form surname "BB" and first name "AA". I gave the name similarly in US Visa application [F1]. But the concerned officer at Visa Application Center rightly told me that they go by the name in passport and surname is mandatory to issue US Visa. She suggested me to make a correction to the name in visa application as surname "AA BB" and first name "FNU" [First Name Unavailable]. So if my visa is approved it will have my name as AA BB, FNU.

How do I change my name in a passport and US visa from AA BB, FNU, to my actual name BB,AA before going to the USA?

Comment: From the official [website](http://passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/online/faqServicesAvailable) `If you find any mistake/error in the particulars printed in the passport booklet as per the application form submitted, please return the passport for necessary rectification. Any additional fees required to be paid would depend solely on merit of the case as decided by the Assistant Passport Officer )/ Passport Officer ) .` (1/2)

Comment: `If there is a misrepresentation of facts, then penalty could also be imposed. Applicants are requested to apply online with the view to ensure that the passports are delivered without any typographical errors since applicants have themselves fed the data. If you have done a mistake while filling your passport application form i.e. you have filled your full name in the "Given Name" field, then you will need to apply for re-issue of passport for change in personal particulars.` For US visa as long as you have the official name change document or passport in this case you should be fine. (2/2)

Comment: @DipenShah Please do not answer in the comments. Rather, post an actual answer.

Comment: @JoErNanO I wasn't sure of the second part however I found some information on forums that's why I thought posting it as comment is better.

Comment: @DipenShah your answer looks fine to me, please post as an answer so that I can upvote it :)

Comment: @mts There you have it.

Answer (score 3):

From the official [website](http://passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/online/faqServicesAvailable):

> If you find any mistake/error in the particulars printed in the
>   passport booklet as per the application form submitted, please return
>   the passport for necessary rectification. Any additional fees required
>   to be paid would depend solely on merit of the case as decided by the
>   Assistant Passport Officer )/ Passport Officer ). If there is a
>   misrepresentation of facts, then penalty could also be imposed.
>   Applicants are requested to apply online with the view to ensure that
>   the passports are delivered without any typographical errors since
>   applicants have themselves fed the data. If you have done a mistake
>   while filling your passport application form i.e. you have filled your
>   full name in the "Given Name" field, then you will need to apply for
>   re-issue of passport for change in personal particulars.

For US visa as long as you have the official name change document or passport in this case you should be fine.